Categories and subcategories permalinks in Wordpress
In my site i have some categories and subcategories from each category. The problem i gave lies in the urls itself for example, this
urlsiteexample.com/product-category/cat1/sub1/prod1/
contains a product with a subcategory and a category. If i navigate to this link
siteexample.com/product-category/cat1/prod1/  or even at this link
siteexample.com/product-category/sub1/prod1/
it will show correctly the product 1, which is wrong because the url siteexample.com/product-category/cat1/prod1/ doesnt actually exists without the subcategory 1. How do i fix this?
